# When and where to do key configuration at JHipster like data source and app/web server credentials

Tags: mysql, tomcat, spring-boot, glassfish-4, jhipster

Facing issues while working with `GalssFish / TomcateEE7`. Though Yo installation is not giving any errors and creates war, facing few issues while deploying the created war like , expected name space is java.com.sun but org.jcp... etc.

Embedded tomcat failed to initialize the application.

I would like to know when and where to do the key configuration set up.
 we have configuration files after yo jhipster, at `master.xml` and `application-dev.yml` and observed the issues with `slfj` as well.

Any detailed config set up and run helps alot to progess. Kindly let me know.

The following the stack trace while deploying at GlassFish 4.
    `Warning:   AS-DEPLOYMENT-00011`

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/crsh/plugin/PluginLifeCycle
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1220)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1750)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.impl.ModuleScanner.getElements(ModuleScanner.java:297)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.processAnnotations(Archivist.java:585)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:462)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:446)
at org.glassfish.web.deployment.archivist.WebArchivist.postAnnotationProcess(WebArchivist.java:338)
at org.glassfish.web.deployment.archivist.WebArchivist.postAnnotationProcess(WebArchivist.java:91)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readRestDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:420)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:396)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:271)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:280)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:241)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:161)
at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:203)
at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:227)
at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:96)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:881)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:821)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:377)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:253)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:231)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:275)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:133)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:365)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:316)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.crsh.plugin.PluginLifeCycle
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1783)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
... 87 more
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace you're seeing in GlassFish?

Comment: @Matt, disable / comment spring boot logging at Jhipster pom.xml has made the application run. but it is taking lot of memory after we run application.java.

Comment: @Matt, After my Tomcat successful tried to run at GlassFish the following are the stack trace,Looks like server port conflict, can't stop tomcat server either, I have terminated all java process forcefully and started GlassFish again. May be the same issue with Spring boot  like http://newscentral.exsees.com/item/9bc25e10eb8ccd2511a534f54dee4f82-d2f9d5fe8dbed74d81c410ac02b9fb33

Comment: org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
 at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
 at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
 at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:428) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
 at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214) ~sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:343)

Comment: The above stack is while running the Application.java, I tried to deploy with admin console. The following is the stack trace: